# Execute code when loading an Eclipse perspective

Tags: eclipse

I'm creating an Eclipse plug-in which amongst other things creates a new perspective. I want to I execute some code when the perspective loads. Previously I was doing this through `createInitialLayout` of `IPerspectiveFactory` but then I realized that this is for defining the page layout only  and is usually called when when launching the perspective for the first time only.

How can I specify some code to execute whenever the perspective is displayed? (e.g. when it is loaded as the default perspective by Eclipse)

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the IPerspectiveListener interface or the PerspectiveAdapter class, the perspective lifecycle events are explained there.

Comment: It helped thanks! Actually I was after this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797071/execute-code-when-eclipse-workbench-loads but still helped :)